# Existe no Português um equivalente para "-smith"?

Tags: estrangeirismos, tradução-inglês, sufixos

No idioma inglês existe a palavra *smith*, muito utilizada na formação por justaposição de outras palavras. Isoladamente *smith* [significa](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=smith) "alguém que trabalha em algo especificado" (em tradução livre).

A partir desta palavra pode-se uni-la, p.ex. com *[gold](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=gold)* (ouro), formando [*goldsmith*](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=goldsmith) (artesão que trabalha com jóias e ouro). Outras uniões possíveis são [*blacksmith*](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=blacksmith) (ferreiro), [*gunsmith*](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=gunsmith) (armeiro), [*locksmith*](http://www.wordwebonline.com/search.pl?w=locksmith) (chaveiro), entre outras.

Existe no Português um vocábulo com sentido semelhante a *smith*?

Comment: Acho que em quase todos os exemplos, _smith_ significa alguém que trabalha com **metais** (gunsmith, coppersmith, arrowsmith, pewtersmith, ...). (Veja aqui: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/smith?searchDictCode=all)). Exepcões sendo _wordsmith_ ou _tunesmith_ que usam _smith_ (ferreiro) figurativamente.

Comment: Sem pensar muito (o que significa que posso estar a dizer parvoíces), ocorrem-me os -ólogos e os -istas.

Comment: Existem palavras que não tem uma equivalente em outra língua.

Comment: @LucasMotta, Concordo. Com esta pergunta eu gostaria de saber se este é o caso, ou apenas ignorância minha.

Comment: @gmauch não posso responder com certeza, mas acredito que não tenha. Se for exclusivo o trabalho com metais, poderia ser metalúrgico, que deriva de metalurgia.

Comment: O Google tradutor diz ser **ferreiro**

Comment: smith é eiro mesmo. Mas nem todos existem;

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Eu acho que não existe uma palavra / um sufixo que funcione como o *-smith* do inglês, que significa alguém que trabalha com **metais**.

O português usa o sufixo "-eiro" para *smith* (ferreiro), que tem a mesma etimologia que o *[-ier](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=-ier)* do inglês (ou francês) (vindo do latim *-arius*) ou *-ary* ou *-er*.

Profissões com esse sufixo como etimologia incluem

> carpent**er**, glaz**ier**, law**yer**, pott**er**, ...
>   bibliothec**ary**, mission**ary**, ...
>   bak**er**, basket weav**er**, ...

O problema é que *-smith* [é derivado de *smið* do inglês antigo](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=smith) (e tem sufixos correspondentes em outras línguas *germânicas*), mas não existe no latim (nem no francês). As profissões correspondentes no latim usam o sufixo mas geral *-arius* (ou *-tor*).

Comment: *Goldsmith* seria uma excessão? Acredito que a tradução seja *ourives*, ou não?  Nesse caso nem sempre `-smith` implica em `-eiro`.

Comment: @falsarella Só falei sobre a palavra _smith_, não sobre todas as palavras com o sufixo _-smith_. Parece que "ourives" vem do latim _aurifex_ e o sufixo _-fex_ deriva-se de _facere_ (fazer).

Comment: Apenas coloquei em discussão a palavra Goldsmith, que o OP mencionou e não apareceu nas respostas. De qualquer forma, concordo com você, por isso o +1.

Answer (score 6):

Na língua Portuguesa, o sufixo "-eiro" funciona da mesma forma:

- padeiro - aquele que vende pães
- sapateiro - aquele que vende ou conserta sapatos
- barbeiro - aquele que corta cabelos e faz a barba
- lixeiro - aquele que coleta resíduos sólidos
- livreiro - aquele que vende livros
- açougueiro - aquele que trabalha no açougue e vende carnes

Comment: Acho que "-eiro" é mais geral do que "*-smith*" do inglês, que significa alguém que trabalha com metais.

Comment: Dei -1 só porque nada tem a ver o "-eiro" com a ideia do "-smith". Senão o que significa isoladamente eiro?

Comment: @JorgeB.  "-eiro" é um sufixo que, ao contrário de "smith", isoladamente não significa nada. Contudo, da mesma forma que smith, quando acrescentado a algumas palavras, forma o nome de muitas profissões.  Essa é a analogia.

Comment: mas essa analogia é com o *-er* como o @Earthliŋ disse e muito bem.

Comment: *Goldsmith* seria uma excessão? Acredito que a tradução seja *ourives*, ou não?  Nesse caso nem sempre `-smith` implica em `-eiro`.

Answer (score 1):

Além do sufixo "-eiro", como bem apontado por outros respondedores, também se usam os sufixos "-or", "-dor", "-tor", ou "-ista" em algumas atividades.

Na Wikipédia há uma lista (incompleta) de profissões, no final do artigo [Profissão](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profiss%C3%A3o). Talvez ela possa ajudar.

Comment: Sim, eiro ou or, dor, tor e ista.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que o termo adequado se refere à um especialista ou artesão/ourives. Não é um sufixo, mas creio que se encaixa melhor se o objetivo for encontrar uma tradução adequada.